# ipfw resetting after reboot

Tags: ipfw

I added a rule in my ipfw a time ago and now I want to delete it. So i go:
sudo ipfw flush
And all user rules gets deleted. But everytime i restart the machine the rule is back again!

I tried looking for some ipfw config file, but has not find anything. When I added the rule the first time i user WaterRoof (frontend for ipfw), could that have somthing to do with this? (I also tried removing the rule with WaterRoof, but same result)

Any ideas on where this rule gets added every time? I don't know where to start.

Im running OS X 10.6

Answer (score 0):

Hmpf... It was Internet Sharing that added the rule, when I turned it of it all went back to normal.

Answer (score -1):

Should be the same for OSX. Run:

```
cat /etc/rc.conf |grep -i "firewall"
```

You should see:

```
firewall_script="/etc/ipfw.rules"
```

Modify whatever file that parameter is using.